# Digital Services Performance Measurement Framework for measuring and monitoring user experience

Tags: metrics, customer-experience

From the framework developed by GSA’s Digital Services Innovation Center that aims to:

> identify a common approach to collect standard data, and enable
> aggregation of this data

The framework is based on the following types of measures:

- Breadth
- Depth
- Loyalty
- Customer Experience

Where customer experience is measured through standard service measures of quality, experience, and loyalty

Is a similar approach also commonly used for user experience measurement and monitoring, or are there similar standards that have been used for the private or commercial sector?

**UPDATE**: Australia's Digital Transformation Agency has also provided guidelines around the [measuring of digital services performance](https://www.dta.gov.au/help-and-advice/digital-service-standard/digital-service-standard-criteria/11-measure-performance), in the form of KPIs below:

- user satisfaction — to help continually improve the user experience
  of your service
- digital take-up — to show how many people are using the service and
  to help encourage users to choose the digital service
- completion rate — to show which parts of the service you need to fix
- cost per transaction — to make your service more cost efficient

This information is collected and displayed at a government services performance dashboard website: https://dashboard.gov.au/

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Are you looking to measure user/customer experience continuously and on large scale, as part of or in addition to what you described from GSA?

Comment: @greenforest to answer your question and further clarify my question, GSA's Digital Services Performance Framework talks about measuring the customer experience by monitoring quality, experience and loyalty, so I am wondering if these are similar measures that have been established by private and commercial organisations for work out the user experience of their products and services or are other metrics used for this.

Comment: Could the HEART framework from Google be useful for this purpose?

Comment: @greenforest Possibly, although I don't know if many people actually use the HEART framework. Do you have experience with it?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment @Michael Lai♦ I have some experience with the HEART framework. It's important to understand that it is a framework to think about measuring and not the actual measuring or KPI. Applying this framework will lead to many KPIs, specific for the product in question, to measure the different parts and questions in the experience.

Comment: @greenforest perhaps you would to like to expand on this and turn the comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of frameworks used to measure UX performance the two I've seen are the Google HEART framework and more recently I found the USER framework from VMware.

https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/google-s-heart-framework-for-measuring-ux

https://medium.com/vmwaredesign/user-metrics-fd8e56914321

I recently liked the way the VMWare proposition was more prescribed than HEART and I think in some ways easier to build around.
Also the way they look at the `R` is really interesting, particularly about transitioning from a "aha" to "habit", so less about individual workflows and more about a holistic view of how sticky/habitual the user behaviour is.

Comment: +1 I haven't heard about USER so I am going to take a look :)

Comment: I found it only days ago, but really like it! would love to know your thoughts.